# onclick check if that element not hasClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check on click that div or li any element not `hasClass()` then do something.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click',function() {
    if(!(this).hasClass("help-icons") && !(this).hasClass("help") && (this).hasClass("close")){
    $(".help-icons").hide();
    }else if((this).hasClass("help")){
        $(".help-icons").show();
     }else{
       $(".help-icons").hide();
     }
    });
```

Comment: Typo. `(this)` needs to be `$(this)`

Comment: One wonders why the document would have those classes, or any classes at all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `$`

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
  if(!$(this).hasClass("help-icons") && !$(this).hasClass("help") && $(this).hasClass("close")) {
    $(".help-icons").hide();
  } else if ( $(this).hasClass("help")) {
    $(".help-icons").show();
  } else {
    $(".help-icons").hide();
  }
});
```